# HTTP Error 500 when loading ~\Content\css in a ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-500

I have a kind of standard MVC web application built with VS Express 2013.

My BundleConfig.cs is like this:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace AcompOrcEst.UI
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.flatly.min.css",
                  "~/Content/Site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using this bootstrap.css alternative theme, bootstrap.flatly.min.css.

The  section of my _Layout.cshtml is like this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title | Gestão do Orçamento Estrutural</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/Content/Imagens/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="icon" href="~/Content/Imagens/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
```

When running the app in my development machine, i.e. localhost server, everything works pretty fine.

So, I published the app to the server (running IIS 7.5). I checked that all the files were copied to the server properly.

But when the app runs in the server the instruction bellow returns the HTTP Error 500!

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

From IE Developer Tools - Network I got the following infos:
[image]

[image]

I've tried changing the bootstrap.flatly.min.csss to the original bootstrap.css. No success!

I have similar apps, running in the very same server, that were built with the very same structure and use the very same style files. The BundleConfig.cs file have the same content, the  section in _Layout.cshtml are the same, except for the ViewBag.Title. And all of them run properly.

I noticed that in the similar apps, the value of Content-Length of that similar request (the bundled css) is much higher: 113004.

So, I think that something, that I don't know what is, is corrupting the loading of the bundled css.

Could anyone help me to figure out what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Paulo Ricardo Ferreira

Comment: Trying to solve the problem and having the app running, I made a change in the <head> of the _Layout.cshtml. I no longer load the bundled css files. I load them directly. It solved the error, but I think it's not the solution. Something wrong is happening with the bundling process and I just don't figure out what it is.

Comment: Did you double check that the files referenced all exist at the path specified?

Comment: @Locke125, yes I did. The files exist so truly that as I didn't use the bundling anymore, I loaded them directly and all the site was properly rendered. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you have a "css" folder in /Content, i've deleted css folder and its works.